# Different questions with the same answer

Tags: discussion

I posted an answer to this question: [hanging references using \fullcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13272/hanging-references-using-fullcite).

A few hours later someone else posted this question: [\fullcite not printing references in apa format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13348/fullcite-not-printing-references-in-apa-format).

The answer to both questions is exactly the same.  Should I post my answer in two places, or should the questions be merged?

Comment: merging seems sensible in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that in this case then merging seems a reasonable thing to do, particularly as the questioner in the second case says that the answer to the first solves their problem.

But I would caution against drawing a general conclusion from this specific case.  The answers being the same does not imply that the questions were the same, and I think that merging implies that they are.

Comment: To add to your general conclusion, if two different questions can be answered identically, giving a full answer to one and a pointer to it with a one-line summary to the other question will suffice.  This isn't a problem case.

Comment: @Charles: Exactly.

Comment: It turned out in the particular examples I mention, the questions morphed into things that required separate answers.  I've accepted this answer because I think that most cases will match Andrew's second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Not an an answer, but rather another case: The question [How to disable the prompt on error?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13323/how-to-disable-the-prompt-on-error) looks like a duplicate and/or merge candidate of those three question to me: [Ignore compile errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/ignore-compile-errors) (as mentioned by Alan), [Suppressing error messages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2584/suppressing-error-messages) (interestingly, this one has very different answers), [How to prevent pdflatex to stop working due to an invalid input file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12770/how-to-prevent-pdflatex-to-stop-working-due-to-an-invalid-input-file)