# Reopen more detailed question

Tags: discussion, duplicates, closed-questions

The question

- [1] [Latex or PdfLatex to generate DVI](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98704/latex-or-pdflatex-to-generate-dvi)

has been closed as a duplicate of

- [2] [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat)

[1] includes more low-level detail, including, crucially, the error message `latex` gives if you try to include a PDF, `! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in platform.pdf (no BoundingBox ).`.  I'd like to reopen [1], so that closer duplicates of it, such as

- [3] https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98723/unable-to-fix-the-figure-attachment-error

can be redirected to an answer that addresses the questioners problem in a more immediately obvious manner.

Cf. [Same disease, different symptoms](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/same-disease-different-symptoms)

Answer (score 9):

I somehow agree that [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98704/latex-or-pdflatex-to-generate-dvi) is good since it includes the error you get. That is a reason why dupe questions are usually not deleted, and certainly not in such cases.

Still, this is not really "different symptoms", and if one finds [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98704/latex-or-pdflatex-to-generate-dvi) and gets to [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat) from there, the answers there it is clear that: "Oh I can't use pdf figures and dvi mode at once!"

So in my opinion, if something has to be done, an information should be added to the general question [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat) in cases you need to mix PDF and DVI mode. It is IMHO better to have the relevant information at one place, and [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat) seems to be quite well suited for that.

Comment: It's not truly "different symptoms" (though more symptoms are on display in [1] than [2]) but the point about ease of recognising what is going on with the problem still applies here, I think.

Comment: I guess that, in particular, this error message is confusing: one might think Latex wouldn't complain about not being able to find a PDF's bounding box if it couldn't handle PDFs, so one would not normally think to ask about which graphics types the DVI path can handle.  There's a bit of a bendy road here.